# my android app run on emulator and run on android devices but does not login page work in mobile devices

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

my android app run on emulator and run on android devices but does not login , it give me localhost error with username and password, so please help me what type of permission I should give in database, I used to MYSQL database and WAMP server

Comment: use ipv4 instead of localhost, i guest that's cause a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database is local, you should add Read permissions
(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
And if it's internet database, you'll need internet permissions
("android.permission.INTERNET")
Also, I'd suggest you to make sure you are on the correct network \ addressing the correct IP, seeing as you get "localhost error" usually means you are addressing your own IP address. Just mentioning this, in case that is not the desired behavior you want from your app.
Also, providing code will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Localhost will not work on physical devices. You need to ipv4 and port to connect to the database.